# What is the name of this category of videos?

Tags: information-graphics, video

I've seen a trend in scientific videos/tutorials where the concept at hand is being sketched out, either by hand for real, or emulated by making it appear as if the images are handdrawn (while still beeing computer images)

e.g. like this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_I94-tJlovg

Is there a name for this specific graphical style of videos?
And, are there public software to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Whiteboard animation** or **Whiteboard videos**

The term whiteboard animation comes from the process of someone drawing on a whiteboard and recording it. The actual effect is a time-lapse, or sometimes stop-motion. Actual animation is rarely used but has been incorporated. Other terms are video scribing, and animated doodling. These video animation styles are now seen in many variations, and have taken a turn into many other animation styles. With the introduction of software to create the whiteboard animations, the process has many different manifestations of varying quality.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteboard_animation